# AngularJS : factory function undefined in controller

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller, angularjs-factory

I used to make it work the exact same way before, and it's driving me crazy. I want to perform a $http GET call into a factory and then get back the result into the controller, to be processed.

The **factory** (don't pay attention to the madness of the request url ):

```
App.factory('MessageFactory', function ($http) {
        var MessageFactory = {
            getCast: function () {
                var request = {
                    method: "GET",
                    url: spHostUrl + "/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('" + listTitle + "')/items?$select=AuthorId,Author/Name,Author/Title,Type_x0020_message,Title,Modified,Body,Expires,Attachments&$expand=Author/Id",
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
                    }
                };

                $http(request)
                .then(function (res) {
                    return res.data;
                }).catch(function (res) {
                    console.error("error ", res.status, res.data);
                }).finally(function () {
                    console.log("end");
                });
            }
        };
        return MessageFactory;
    });
```

Now the **controller** :

```
App.controller('MessageController', function ($scope, $http, $log, $attrs, MessageFactory) {
        $scope.messages = MessageFactory;
        MessageFactory.getCast().then(function (asyncCastData) {
            $scope.messages.cast = asyncCastData;
        });
        $scope.$watch('messages.cast', function (cast) {
            //do stuff
        });
});
```

When I test it I get the following error :

> Error: MessageFactory.getCast(...) is undefined
>   @/Scripts/App.js:167:9

The line 167 is indeed this line in the controller

```
MessageFactory.getCast().then(function (asyncCastData) {
```

My app works fine for any other feature, so my issue appeared when adding this part, and I'm pretty sure my controller doesn't know my factory yet and thus try to access to his function. As it's an asynchronous call, it should work with the code in the controller. I need your help on this, thanks.

Comment: you must be getting `.then` of undefined error..Am right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You must be getting .then of undefined error

Because you missed to return promise from service method.

**Service**

```
var MessageFactory = {
  getCast: function() {
    var request = {
      method: "GET",
      url: spHostUrl + "/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('" + listTitle + "')/items?$select=AuthorId,Author/Name,Author/Title,Type_x0020_message,Title,Modified,Body,Expires,Attachments&$expand=Author/Id",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
      }
    };

    return $http(request) //returned promise from here
      .then(function(res) {
        return res.data;
      }).catch(function(res) {
        console.error("error ", res.status, res.data);
      }).finally(function() {
        console.log("end");
      });
    }
};
```

Comment: thanks a lot I though that returning the data retrivied in the "then" section would be sufficient !